# direct cmd output to variable using pipes

Tags: cmd

I am trying see how many files how been updated today. So I am running:

```
forfiles /P C:\Directory\ /S /D %DATE:~4,10% | wc -w
```

now I am trying to set the result to a variable but cant' seem to get it work with:

```
@echo off set files=forfiles /P C:\Directory\  /S /D %DATE:~4,10% | wc -w
```

when I use `echo "%files%"` I get : %files% as output.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong. I am new to cmd coming from unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 
for /f %%c in ('forfiles /P C:\Directory\  /S /D %DATE:~4,10% ^| wc -w') do set files=%%c
echo %files% found
```

(untested)

Comment: %%c was unexpected at this time. is the error I get

Comment: this might be because of %DATE% but I am not sure.

Comment: This is a batch file. If you are executing directly from the prompt, change `%%c` to `%c` throughout